# How does cpu interpet op codes

Tags: computer-building

I want to build a very simple computer from ICs but have a question.
When it reseves the op code does the cpu use hard coded xnor gates to "decode" the op code or is there some other magic going on?

Comment: Depends on the architecture.  Some CPUs employ microprogramming: the opcode is used as an index or address into the **control store** to execute microcode to perform the instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gates.  Lots and lots of them.  But I'm assuming you're not building out of just simple gates.  Why not use de-multiplexers too, and all the myriad of other chips that are out there to deal with digital logic.

So I'm curious.  Why are you doing what you are doing?

Comment: Demultiplexers, I have thought of using them but can't find a good deal. What Ime building is basically a computer that can be programmed using commands like WRT ADD STORE GOTO ect. Some thing like this... http://images.pcworld.com/images/article/2012/05/almost-11354889.jpeg

Comment: Cool!  Don't know what logic family you are designing in but here is an example of what I am talking about:  http://www.jameco.com/1/3/cmos-demultiplexer  Data sheet here:  http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/44927.pdf